# nginx - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: nginx, coredump, fault

I installed nginx-extras and passenger from Phusion's PPA and I can't get nginx to start.

```
$ sudo service nginx restart
* Restarting nginx nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx: line 46: 32069 Segmentation fault (core dumped) start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PID --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS 2> /dev/null
```

What's the best way to approach this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Problems? -> Logs! Always! Immediately! Something like (`sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log` and) `sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`. You can even put both file paths behind tail command.

To find your logs:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mlocate
sudo updatedb
sudo locate error.log
```

If you don't have logs you can start nginx directly and don't pass `2> /dev/null` to it. Or using `sudo journalctl -f -u nginx` on Ubuntu maybe.

Comment: Logs don't say anything when this happens. It's a core dump, which is a catastrophic failure in Nginx itself, outside of the scope of app code.

Answer (score -1):

Wait for Nginx to fix this bug.

I'll delete or update this answer if anyone has a better idea.